# $S:=\left\{\left(m+n\right)^{\frac1{mn}}:\;m,n\in\mathbb N\right\}\inf S,\sup S$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, supremum-and-infimum, solution-verification

If exist, find $\sup S,\inf S$
$$S:=\left\{\left(m+n\right)^{\frac{1}{mn}}:\;m,n\in\Bbb N\right\}$$
$$m=1,n=1:\;\left(m+n\right)^{\frac{1}{mn}}=2$$

For a fixed $m\in\Bbb N,n\to\infty\quad$:

**Error pointed out** by @FimPellizieri and @Peterforeman in the comments **corrected**:
$$(m+n)^{\frac1{mn}}=\left(n\left(1+\frac{m}n\right)\right)^{\frac1{mn}}=\left(n^{\frac1n}\right)^{\frac1m}\cdot\left(\left(1+\frac{m}n\right)^{\frac{n}m}\right)^{\frac1{n^2}}=1$$

---

Original question (the accepted answer is still correct):

Is this correct?

Comment: That limit is not $e$. It is of the determinate form $(1+0)^0=1$. You should get $S\subseteq(1,2]$.

Comment: It appears you mistook $\left(1+\frac{n}{m}\right)^{\frac{1}{m}}$ for $\left(1+\frac{n}{m}\right)^m$.

Comment: @PeterForeman, thank you, I see the mistake, it is $\frac{1}{m}$ not $m$

Comment: @Fimpellizieri, yes, that is exactly what I've done, without even noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$\frac \partial{\partial m} {\left(m+n\right)}^{1/mn}
=
{\left(m+n\right)}^{1/mn}\left(\frac1{mn(m+n)}-\frac{\log(m+n)}{m^2n}\right)$$

We see that $\frac \partial{\partial m} {\left(m+n\right)}^{1/mn} < 0$ if and only if

$$\begin{align}
&\,\,\,\frac1{mn(m+n)}-\frac{\log(m+n)}{m^2n} < 0
\\\iff&m<(m+n)\log(m+n)
\\\iff&e^m<(m+n)^{m+n}
\end{align}$$

If $m=n=1$, already this is true, and increasing $n$ or $m$ only makes it more so.
Therefore, $\frac \partial{\partial m} {\left(m+n\right)}^{1/mn} < 0$ for all $m,n\geqslant 1$.

It follows that $\sup S$ is attained when $m=n=1$ and $\inf S$ is attained as $m,n\to\infty$, so $\sup S = 2$ and $\inf S = 1$.